# How can I set path for my Shell Script in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, run-configuration

I want to set **Script Path** for my script in android project without using a strict path(`/User/Documents/MyApp/tools/script.sh`) as well as **"Working directory"**.

I know that I can use **"External tools"** but this solution doesn't work because all project developers will have to import my jar file with "external tools" settings

Can I somehow write this **path** using **$ProjectFileDir$** variables?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

As of now, there is [no direct way to use these variables](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207004265-Can-I-specify-startup-shutdown-script-path-as-relative-to-project-directory) in the path values of configurations.

Alternatively, you can create a `gradle` `task` in `app/gradle` file to run your shell scripts:

```
task runSS {
    doLast{
        exec {
            // chmod u+rwx demo.sh to make file executable
            executable "../demo.sh"
        }
    }
}

// other gradle tasks
```

> Make sure to change the permission of the file to executable by using `chmod u+rwx file_name`.

Now run the file:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: hmm, an interesting solution, I'll try this if the community does not suggest anything more suitable

Comment: the solution is not very suitable because the script has input parameters and you have to wait for the project configuration